# Use @NameBinding with Apache tomee

Tags: java, apache, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I try to create a JAXRS ContainerResponseFilter for my Apache tomee webapps.

First here my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0-6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

...

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <context>ROOT</context>
                <libs>
                    <lib>javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1</lib>
                    <lib>javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2</lib>
                </libs>
                <tomeeClassifier>jaxrs</tomeeClassifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My interface :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@NameBinding
public @interface CrossDomain {}
```

My filter implementation :

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@CrossDomain
public class CrossDomainProvider implements ContainerResponseFilter
{

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext creq, ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException
{
    final Logger Log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrossDomainProvider.class);
    Log.debug("FILTER CROSS ! ");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
}

}
```

My rest service :

```
@Path("/groups")
@CrossDomain
public class GroupRestService
{
@EJB
private GroupService groupService;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Group> getAllGroups()
{
    return groupService.findAllGroups();
}

@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Group getGroupById(@PathParam("id")String id)
{
    return groupService.findGroupById(id);
}
}
```

My project compiles well, I can even access to my webservice with localhost host but it never go inside my filter and if I try to use an external host then it doesn't work. I can't never see my piece of Log in console.

Comment: Namebinding is not introduced until JAX-RS 2.0. You can't just add the 2.0 API jar and expect it to work. TomEE uses a JAX-RS 1.1 implementation, so you're outa luck. Same with your `ContainerResponseFilter`. That is also a JAX-RS 2.0 class. I suggest you get rid of that JAX-RS 2.0 dependency so you don't get confused on what you can an cannot use

Comment: Thank you ! That'll teach me to use copy/paste from another no-tomee project without reflexion : /